# name of function $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ and the sequence it generates

Tags: numerical-methods

this is a very trivial question, but I couldn't find what the proper name a function of the form 
$x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$, where $f: X \rightarrow Y$ for some initial $x_0$ is, and what the the sequence $(x_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ which generates is called?

As well what a sequence of functions $(f^{(i)})_{i=0}^{\infty}$ for $f:X \rightarrow Y$, and $f^{(m)}$ is the composure of $f$ with itself $m$ times.

Thanks a bunch for your help

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Could you spend a little time expanding upon the contents of your question, perhaps adding something called a "question mark"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a [fixed-point iteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration).

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I was wondering whether that was the case, but thought that that was only the method class of numerical methods.

Answer (score 0):

$Y$ must be the same as $X$ for $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$ to make sense.

In this case:

- the sequence $(x_n)$ is called the *orbit* of $x_0$ under $f$.
- $f$ is called a *map* on $X$.
- a composition of $f$ with itself several times is called an *iterate* of $f$.

This terminology is used in discrete dynamical systems.